# Does Parse API allow access to its source ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

I'm integrating Parse API to my Android project in Eclipse. 
I had just downloaded Parse-1.7.1.jar from the website and here are the files in the zip folder.

[image]

I was able to attach the javadoc to my project. However, I couldn't find the source attachment. So, everytime when I try to open a class from Parse api eg ParseUser, I will run into this error.
[image]

Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Parse.com SDK for Android is not open source project, so you won't be able to attach sources at Eclipse.